# Xamarin NSTime RepeatingScheduledTimer is not getting called on Release Mode - Backgroud

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, background, nstimer

In my application, I have created `NSTimer` event that gets triggered every 5 minutes, nevertheless, it's in the background or foreground. The application will check for local content in DB & check if it is required to Sync. The applications work as expected in debug mode, on both simulator & device.

However, when I create a Release build, the NSTimer task, stops the firing task in the background. Would like to know the cause of this behavior in Xamarin.IOS?

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` is not allowed to run in background if you do not enable any background mode ,  the system will suspend your app shortly after it moves to the background.

However there are several options for refreshing content in the background

- Region Monitoring and Significant Location Changes Service
- Background Fetch (iOS 7+)
- Remote Notifications (iOS 7+)

Refer to

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127444

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/updating-an-application-in-the-background

- Remote Notifications (iOS 7+)

Comment: Both Background modes were enabled, still, the NSTimer failed to load. Is this common behavior?

Comment: I mean you don't need to use `Timer`, the three ways are more proper to update the content in background.